# How can I efficiently extract data from pdf by looping through each line and extracting the characters in between a specific pattern of strings?

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I'm attempting to parse text data from a pdf application using:

```
    Credibly_text <- pdf_text("Credibly_Business__Funding 
    _Application(385).pdf") %>%
      readr::read_lines()

    reducedWhitespace <- Credibly_text[9:45] %>%
      str_squish()
```

which returns lines that look like:

```
    [1] "Legal/corporate name: RTT Enterprises Inc. DBA: RTT Enterprises 
    Inc."                                       
    [2] "Physical address: 2145 W Suhest St City: Springfield State: MO 
    Zip: 65807"                                  
    [3] "Mailing Address: 2145 W Suhest St City: Springfield State: MO 
    Zip: 65807"                                   
    [4] "Federal tax ID: 208088643 Business phone: 4178485439 Fax:"                                                  
    [5] "Contact: Richard Hare Email: rchare1@msn.com Website: 
    airservicesheatac.com"                                
    [6] "Date business started: 01/01/1964 Length of ownership: 2006-12-26 
    Years at location: 12 # of locations: 1"
```

So far I have been extracting the values that I need by using a brute force method:

```
    temp <- reducedWhitespace[[1]]
    res <- str_match(temp, "name: (.*?) DBA")
    values[[1]] <- res[,2]
    values[[1]]
```

which returns:

```
    "RTT Enterprises Inc."
```

This feels way too inefficient and I was wondering if there was a way to loop through each line and identify the strings that I need to get the value between. I am very inexperienced with regex so I'm having trouble accounting for cases where in one line you can have

```
    "Physical address: 2145 W Suhest St City:"
```

which I know you can just extract a string between strings that end with a colon. But then cases where the last string contains a space:

```
    "Federal tax ID: 208088643 Business phone:"
```

or when the needed string is not between two strings that end in a colon but only comes after one such as:

```
    "Zip: 65807"
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about overlap too much. You can write an alternation regex with separate capture groups. Only 1 group will match. Use it as a flag to see which data you've captured.

Comment: Are the field names (like 'Physical address,' 'Business phone,' etc.) stable across all documents? If so, once you know what they are it shouldn't be too much effort to get everything between those fields. The tricky part is if you don't know what all the fields are, in which case you would need to have the regex find the fields. the harder to catch cases would be those where the field name contains a space, but at least in the examples it looks like those fields are always preceded by numbers, which would give you a pattern to look for.